# codificación idioma español-italiano carácter diferente navegador

Tags: laravel, html5, css3, utf-8, navegador-web

Buen dia. tengo un problema con la codificación de letras en esta pagina web [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde todo combinación de letra "fi" lo cambia por "ä" en el navegador italiano. Es decir en mi navegador se ve bien la palabra " efficace"  pero en navegadores italianos se ve efäcace.

El texto  proviene tanto de base de datos como de plantilla blade usando @lang()"LARAVEL"

en el header tengo la siguiente meta

```
<html lang={{app()->getLocale()}}>
<head>
    <title>Koine | @yield('title')</title>
<!--    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> -->
  <meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1″ />
```

**HE PROBADO AMBOS META SOLOS O JUNTOS**

Y  no consigo solución

necesito ayuda con 2 puntos

1-) Por favor como resolver el cambio de palabra en la imagen

2-) para futuros proyectos como puedo replicar este error en mi navegador ya que he cambiado a vpn cambiado el idioma del crome y en mi caso sale bien pero de mi cliente en ITALIA da ese problema

Saludos

Comment: Vale no se si sabes pero Laravel te da la opción de crear tus librerías para las traducciones, yo por lo menos es lo que uso cuando creo un proyecto en Laravel el cual usa más de un Idioma. Te dejo la documentación de Laravel para que lo veas: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization

Comment: si exactamente ya eso esta implementado tengo vistas en "lang->en-web" y "lang-it->web" y usando App::setLocale($locale) establece "it" o "en"  en ingles todo se ve bien pero en it esta el problema comentado